# qqplot (and other plots for diagnostics) after AIC using train() function

Tags: r, plot, regression, r-caret

I am fitting OLS with stepwise variable selection, using train() function.

After I run the model and try to plot qqplot using plot() it plots the RMSE depending on maximum number of predictors.

Is there a way to plot qqplot and other diagnostic plots after the model above?

The code I wrote is as below:

```
OLS_AIC_CV = train(Variable ~ . , data = df_train_all, 
                       method = "leapSeq", 
                       trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3), 
                       tuneGrid = data.frame(nvmax = 1:10) 
                   )   

plot(OLS_AIC_CV)
```

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried `plot(OLS_AIC_CV$finalModel)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this: from the stepwise selection, select the best subset of variable, re-fit an `lm` model with the best subset and then extract the qqplot from the new `lm` obkect.

```
data("mtcars")
library(caret)
set.seed(5)
OLS_AIC_CV = train(mpg ~ . , data = mtcars, 
                   method = "leapSeq", 
                   trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3), 
                   tuneGrid = data.frame(nvmax = 1:10) 
)   

fit <- OLS_AIC_CV$finalModel
#extract the best subset of variable 
x <- summary(fit)$which[2,-1]
new.df <- mtcars[,x]
#refit the lm model 
OLS <-  train(
  mpg ~ .,
  data = new.df,
  method = "lm",
  trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3)
)   
#plot the qqplot 
plot(OLS$finalModel,2)
```